# how to combine forall with a relational approach in generating results

Tags: prolog

I wrote a predicate `aux_cond1(Assoc0, X, Assoc1)` which takes as an input `X`, does some search on a graph, and if some condition cond1 holds inserts X into the `Assoc0`, generating a new `Assoc1`.

To traverse the graph I want to use forall/2 such as:

```
forall(pattern(X, Y), cond1(Assoc0, X, Assoc1))
```

However this will not work since for each successful application of Cond1/3 for found pattern(X,Y), Assoc0 is supposed to be changed to Assoc1.

What is the preferred forall pattern for relational predicates such as cond1/3, so that for each pattern(X,Y) identify a new, and potentially, backtrackable, Assoc1 is created.

EDIT:

I think i found a pattern that could work:

instead of using forall/2, I could use findall/3, generating the list of results, and then call an aux_cond1 with the generated list -- aux_cond1 in turn splits the list into head and tail and calls cond1 for each head.

This seems ok as long as the generated list with findall is reasonably short.

Comment: `Y` isn't used at all, so you really could say, `pattern(X, _)`?

Comment: Thank you. Y is actually bound, which can't be seen in the example I gave here.

Comment: Tomas -- looks like I encountered exactly what you mentioned -- the loss of earlier results through backtracking. 

Is it a problem, relationally speaking, if i do make one strategic placement of a cut. It ensures that one kind of backtracking does not occur where a failure should signal a real failure and conclusion of the search.

Comment: Explicit cuts are never needed (afaik). Just add conditions, e.g. tests for inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The forall/2 is not suitable for a chaining task, since it will undo variable bindings. It is defined as follows:

```
 forall(C, A) :- \+ (C, \+ A).
```

You are right that you might have more success with findall/3. If you write your aggregator as cond1(X, Assoc0, Assoc1), you can even use foldl/4 and divert into so called higher order programming. Example:

```
p(1).
p(2).
p(3).
p(4).

cond(X, [X|L], L) :- X > 2, !.
cond(_, L, L).
```

We can now query:

```
?- findall(X, p(X), L), foldl(cond, L, R, []).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4],
R = [3, 4].
```